# Non linear approximation of function (c# .net and Math)

Tags: c#, math, regression

I have a function on the form `y = a/(a-(x+b))` and several couple of data `{x, y}`.
I need to approximate a and b using those data, so maybe a non linear regression.

How can I do that, and possibly implement it in **C#** ?

Thanks for your answers.
Bastien

Comment: In case you can not solve this algebraically or geometrically then: either you do `O(n^2)` brute force search or if the `a,b` have monotonic dependence on `y` and `x` then you can use binary search `O(log^2(n))` but for arbitrary approximation you can use the answers in the duplicate QA I linked (see the examples in there).

Comment: Why can't you do a least squares fit to approximate the function?  How accurate do you need to be?  A conjugate gradient solution will get you there.  Your range has to exclude the point x = (a-b); it's singular there.

Comment: [Math.Net](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/regression.html) has some linear regression stuff that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonlinear regression can be hard. If you know how to do linear regression, you can transform your function/data to make it to a linear regression problem, In your case, if you define a new variable `z=1/y`, then your problem is going to be:

find a line with equation `a + b - x = a z` that best fits the data set `{(x0, z0=1/y0), (x1, z1=1/y1), ...}`

Comment: Thank you, this will definitelly what I will do !